# Processor throttling in Windows.

Tags: windows

Is there any way or tools to make my PC slow?

When I make applications I want to see how do they appear on a low-end PC.

I want to test Java Script applications, but I appreciate a general way to make my PC slow!

Comment: What about a VM you have starved for resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own power plan where you can limit maximum processor state to 5% for example. Open the Power options menu and click "create a power plan" or you can modify any of the existing power plans by clicking on "change plan settings" and then click on "change advanced power settings". Here you can tweak "Processor power management"/"Maximum processor state" as you need. This should work in Windows 8.1. Win 7 should be similar. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"Processor affinity" determines which CPU cores a program can use. You can use Task Manager to limit your browser to one CPU core, which already takes away quite some performance. As a bonus, the other CPU cores remain available so your PC doesn't become sluggish.